# Paper.js: fastest way to draw many iterated shapes over loop

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas, refactoring, paperjs

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yw0w18m3/2/

I'm using paper.js to make a background image that looks somthing like this:

[image]

Basically, I'm creating a couple thousand triangles over a loop and rotating them on every other iteration.

```
function Tri(x, y, rotate) {
    var tri = new Path([
        new Point((x - 42), (y - 48)),
        new Point((x - 42), y),
        new Point(x, (y - 24)), 
        new Point((x - 42), (y - 48)) 
    ]);

    tri.fillColor = {
        hue: Math.random() * 360,
        saturation: 0,
        brightness: ( (( Math.random() ) * .95) + .3 )
    };

    if(rotate) { tri.rotate(180); } 
}

for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    rotate = false;

    if( i % 2 ) {
        rotate = true;
    }

    new Tri(x, y, rotate);

    x = x + 42;

    if( x > (winWidth + 42) ) {
        x = 0   ;
        y = y + 24;
    }
}
```

There seems to be a brief 1-2 second pause/freeze though while the shapes are being drawn. Is there a more efficient way to draw all the shapes first (or push to an array) then add *that* to the canvas all at once?

I based my code off of the example here: http://paperjs.org/examples/candy-crash/ (click "source" in the upper right corner).

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would end up creating two triangles, one rotated, so they don't have to be built from new points each time. Then choose the correct triangle based on the rotation variable and clone it, as opposed to create points and a triangle from scratch each time. Finally, just change the position of the cloned triangle.

Last, I would correct the maxTri so it doesn't do more than it needs to. The paren should follow the 48, not the 24. You're doing an order of magnitude more triangles than needed.

Here's a link to the [sketch.paperjs.org](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) solution I created based on your code. I find sketch easier to use than jsfiddle for paper examples.

```
proto1 = new Path([
    new Point(0, -24),
    new Point(0, 24),
    new Point(42, 0)
    ]);
proto1.closed = true;

proto2 = proto1.clone();
proto2.rotate(180);


function putTriangle(pos, rotate) {
    var tri = (rotate ? proto2 : proto1).clone();
    tri.position = pos;
    tri.position = tri.position.subtract([21, 0])
    tri.fillColor = {
        hue: Math.random() * 360,
        saturation: 0,
        brightness: Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.5
    }
}
var tris = [],
    x = 42,
    y = 24,
    rotate,
    winWidth = paper.view.size.width,
    winHeight = paper.view.size.height,
    rows = (winHeight + 48) / 24,
    cols = (winWidth + 42) / 42,
    numTri = rows * cols,
    numTriOrig = (winWidth + 42) / 42 * (winHeight + 48 / 24);

//console.log(numTri, numTriOrig);

x = 0;
y = 0;

for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    rowrotate = row % 2;
    for (var col = 0; col <= cols; col++) {
        rotate = rowrotate ^ col % 2;
        putTriangle([x,y], rotate);
        x += 42;
    }
    x = 0;
    y = y + 24;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

I see you use rotate to transform you triangles into place. This is an expensive operation. You could replace the rotate with a less geometric & more arithmetic calculation of the triangles orientation.

Also, I see is that the fill color is being changed with each triangle and state changes (like fill) are modestly expensive. You could group all the similarly colored triangles and draw them in a single batch.